# Rejected from review. With varnish error - page doesn't contain HIT in cache header

Tags: php, magento, module, magento2, varnish

I'm new in Magento extension development and have some problem with publication my extension to marketplace. I can't find some useful info about this problem on the Internet.

Problem is with varnish - **HIT**, after question on [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221664/rejected-from-review-some-problem-with-varnish?noredirect=1#comment307703_221664).

was added `catcheble = "true"` to all blocks as described in [Installation issue in magento marketplace 'page doesn't contain HIT in cache header.'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208540/installation-issue-in-magento-marketplace-page-doesnt-contain-hit-in-cache-hea?noredirect=1&lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) in [Miguel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/54652/miguel) post.

I get all (two) value of header: **MISS** and **HIT**.

Regarding to [Magento2: Error validating extension in marketplace](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208706/magento2-error-validating-extension-in-marketplace/212739#212739) and [Pramod Kumar Sharma](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/3720/pramod-kumar-sharma) answer - variable **_isScopePrivate** is false.

Please maybe some of you can help with it, I can't find some useful information on the Internet.

Thanks.

Screen from marketplace below.

[image: Errors during installation]

Comment: Have you getting any solution for it ? If Yes then post your answer here. I am stuck with this issue.